# Expected number of buckets an object appears in

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose you have a set of types of objects $V$ where $|V|=C$ and $k$ buckets $b_1, b_2,...,b_k$. Each bucket contains $n_i$ objects of a type randomly chosen from $V$. Note that each bucket may therefore contain the same type of object repeatedly. For any given  $e \in V$, what is the expected number of buckets there is at least one object of type $e$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Are you saying that $V$ consists of $C$ types of objects but that there are as many of any particular type as we need?  So in principle all buckets may contain only examples of type $e$?

Comment: That's right. Each bucket $b_i$ randomly chooses an element $e$ from V $n_i$ times. It may choose the same element more than once. The set $V$ is fixed, the bucket $b_i$ just obtains an object of that type if you will.

Comment: Ok, so then what have you tried?  Indicator variables should work well...let $X_i$ be the event that bucket $i$ contains $e$.  Can you compute $E[X_i]$?